# Exporting String data from Bigquery to GCS (CSV) without double quotes

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a concatenated string in a Bigquery table which has double quotes enclosed while exporting data as CSV to GCS. Is there a way I can avoid double quotes in the files?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the final csv has quotes is because the string contains `','` which is also the default delimiter. Specifying a different delimiter other than `','` should work.
`bq extract --format none --noprint_header --field_delimiter "|" [table_name] [gcs_file_location]`

Comment: if data contains a quote, it will also be exported with quotes added (and the contained quote escaped with "".
Pretty annoying if all you want is for instance exporting a "JSON" format controlling exactly what you put in your JSON using concat.

Answer (score -1):

If feasible, try replacing all double quotes with single quotes by using [`SELECT * REPLACE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-replace) and [`REPLACE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#replace), i.e:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE (REPLACE(fieldWithIssue, '"', "'") AS fieldWithIssue)
FROM yourTable
```

And then attempt to extract again.

Comment: I found this quote option while loading the data into BQ. I want to know if I can skip double quotes while exporting the query results in to GCS.

Comment: @passionate You're correct, I mixed up the 'bq load' command with 'bq extract'. I removed that suggestion from the answer. In any case, I recommend trying to replace the double quotes with single quotes and then attempting the export as per my second suggestion.

Comment: Data does not have double quotes. Because it is a string field, double quotes appear in the text file when I export from BQ. Is there a way I can avoid it?

Comment: @passionate I ran a quick test, and on my end, exports of strings in a BigQuery table do not appear with double quotes in the resulting .csv file in GCS. Could you give some details on how are you exporting? I.e using the Cloud Console, Client libraries, CLI command? If so, which?

Comment: I use this command to export data: `bq extract --format none --noprint_header [table_name] [gcs_file_location]`

The data of the table contains this only field: `CONCAT(Id,",", values) `
where values are coming from a subquery which in turn has concatenated values: `STRING_AGG(CONCAT(CAST(id AS string),',',CAST(count_value AS string)), ','` 

Probably because I have concatenated field, double quotes always appear.

Comment: it is not solving issue as in general, you may have quotes in any field, so you do not know under which field you have to run REPLACE